# Fundamental gap for Neumann BVP with potential

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, linear-pde

I am sure this is extremely well known but I have been digging a bit and I can't find what I need.  Consider $B$ to be the unit ball in $ \mathbb R^N$ and consider the eigenvalue problem

\begin{cases} - \Delta u(x) + u(x) - V(|x|) u(x) = \lambda u(x) & \mbox{in } B \\\partial_\nu u=0  & \partial B. \end{cases}

Here $V(r)$ is some fixed positive function.  Let $ \lambda_1$ denote the first eigenvalue of this problem and let $ \lambda_2$ denote the second.   Are there available lower estimates on $ \lambda_2 - \lambda_1$ in terms of some quantities involving $V$?

Comment: If we introduce $v(|x|)=1-V(|x|)$ then what you have is precisely Schrodinger eigenvalue equation (with Neumann BV) .see of instance [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103922378)

Comment: thank you for the reference.  It appears the reference only considers the Dirichlet problem.  Any idea where I can find a Neumann version of this? thanks

Comment: This is a separable problem, is it not?

Comment: apparently i asked this 5 or 6 years ago... i have no clue what i asked or why or ....